# Androidx, how to know dependency format/string

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

Ok I got that I can found all androidx libraries there:[AndroidX libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions#version-table), but please can someone explain how can I figure out how to properly name them in my dependencies (Android project with Gradle as build system). I would really appreciate some generic scheme for that, as in ex. support libraries, they used to include gradle config for dependencies, now these are gone so I suspect I am missing something very simple that should be applicable to all libraries listed in the link provided.

My attempt with pallete [palette releases](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/palette):

```
implementation 'androidx.palette.graphics:1.0.0'
```

Resulting in `ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.palette.graphics:1.0.0:`
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can go to [maven.google.com](https://maven.google.com/) and see all of the artifacts. There, you can see the artifact group (the top level) is `androidx.palette` and the artifact name (the second level) is `palette`, which means the whole implementation line is

```
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
```

Note the `group:name:version` syntax. This is common across all artifacts everywhere, including across all AndroidX artifacts.

Comment: Ian if you still at Google might be worth suggesting to add that maven.google.com link to docs with migration, maybe my question was a bit stupid but I believe a lot of people will benefit.

Comment: @kolboc - you can file documentation bugs on [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697) - it would probably be useful to file a bug at least to get all of the release notes pages to have a dependencies section (i.e., similar to how [Core](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#declaring_dependencies) is documented). I just don't think Palette has gotten the same amount of love as other libraries.

Answer (score 5):

Here you can find info for the Android KTX which is a set of Kotlin extensions that are included with Android Jetpack and other Android libraries:
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx

To use the palete module, add the following to your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.palette:palette-ktx:1.0.0"
}
```